# Adding Graph*I*QL Subscription Endpoint when Using WebSocketLinks from apollo-link-ws?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, graphiql

Here's my client-side code initializing ApolloClient:

```
import React from "react";
import {Meteor} from "meteor/meteor";
import {render} from "react-dom";
import {ApolloProvider} from "react-apollo";
import {ApolloLink, from} from "apollo-link";
import {ApolloClient} from "apollo-client";
import {HttpLink} from "apollo-link-http";
import {InMemoryCache} from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import {onError} from 'apollo-link-error';
import {split} from 'apollo-link';
import {WebSocketLink} from 'apollo-link-ws';             //<======
import {getMainDefinition} from 'apollo-utilities';
import {toIdValue} from 'apollo-utilities';

import App from "../../ui/App";

// Create an http link:
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: Meteor.absoluteUrl("graphql"),
    credentials: 'same-origin'
})

// Create a WebSocket link:
const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
    uri: `ws://localhost:3200/subscriptions`,
    options: {
        reconnect: true
    }
});

// using the ability to split links, you can send data to each link
// depending on what kind of operation is being sent
const splitLink = split(
    // split based on operation type
    ({query}) => {
        const {kind, operation} = getMainDefinition(query);
        return kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription';
    },
    wsLink,
    httpLink,
);

const authLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
    const token = Accounts._storedLoginToken();
    operation.setContext(() => ({
        headers: {
            "meteor-login-token": token
        }
    }));
    return forward(operation);
});


const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: ApolloLink.from([
        onError(({graphQLErrors, networkError}) => {
            if (graphQLErrors)
                graphQLErrors.map(({message, locations, path}) =>
                    console.log(
                        `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`,
                    ),
                );
            if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
        }),
        authLink,
        splitLink,
     ]),
    cache: new InMemoryCache({})
});

const ApolloApp = () => (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <App/>
    </ApolloProvider>
);

Meteor.startup(() => {
    render(<ApolloApp/>, document.getElementById("app"));
});
```

This works perfectly on the client. And using it graph**I**ql (please note the 'I') works fine for queries and mutations. But graph**I**ql does not yet work for subscriptions, because I haven't yet told it the subscription endpoint.

Searching SO for answers doesn't seem to bring up any that apply when using WebSocketLinks rather than Express.

What's the correct way to tell graph**I**ql the subscription endpoint when using WebSocketLinks?